# How do I get the child of a unique parent in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

My question is about targeting a child with a unique parent. For example. Let's say I have a box people can move called `box_mc` and 3 platforms it can jump on called:

- Platform_1
- Platform_2
- Platform_3

All of these platforms have a child element called hit.

- Platform_1

  - Hit
- Platform_2

  - Hit
- Platform_3

  - Hit

I use an array and a `for each` statement to detect if `box_mc` hits one of the platforms childs.

```
var obj_arr:Array = [Platform_1, Platform_2, Platform_3];
for each(obj in obj_arr){
   if(box_mc.hitTestObject(obj.hit)){
      trace(obj + " " + obj.hit);
      box_mc.y = obj.hit.y - box_mc.height;
   }
}
```

obj seems to output the unique parent it is hitting but obj.hit ouputs hit, so my theory is that it is applying the change of y to all the childs called hit in the stage. Would it be possible to only detect the child of that specific parent?

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the `hitArea` property of your platforms ([AS3 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#hitArea)).

So first make the `hit` children the hitArea of your platforms, like so:

```
var obj_arr:Array = [Platform_1, Platform_2, Platform_3];
for each(obj in obj_arr){
   obj.hitArea = obj.hit;
}
```

Then you can detect collisions with your platforms like so:

```
for each(obj in obj_arr){
   if(box_mc.hitTestObject(obj)){
      // collision occured
   }
}
```

The collision test will be between your `box_mc` and your platforms, but the shape of the `hit` object will be used as collision shape of your platform.

Comment: Hi bummzack, 
Thanks for the answer! I have one more question. The hitarea is not the only child in the platform parent that can be hit. Each platform parent has a hit, bot and base child which the player can hit. Do you perhaps have any tips on how to do this?